# Validation pattern: numbers with up to one letter (optional)

Tags: angular, validation

In Angular I want to validate a field to match the pattern of a number and up to one uppercase letter (123, 17A, 88F, ...)

With this validator the field always exepts a letter, how can I make this pattern item optional?

```
Validators.pattern('[0-9]+' + '[A-Z]{1}')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex you are looking for the `?` which is equivalent to `{0,1}`.

Like this:
`Validators.pattern('[0-9]+[A-Z]?')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` to make the letter optional:

```
Validators.pattern('[0-9]+[A-Z]?')]
```

Note also that I combined your regex pattern into a single string.  I don't see the point of concatenating together the pattern, and also from a maintenance point of view this is not desirable.